# how to order result when using group by or distinct?

Tags: mysql, sql

some dummy data:

```
id  group_id name score
1   A         Tom   20
2   B         Jone  17
3   B         Jack  19
4   C         Tim   18
```

I want to get distinct group_id order by score. Here is my attemp:

`select  group_id from table  order by score` comes out:

```
group_id
B
C
B
A
```

so, i think this will work `select distinct group_id from (select  group_id from table  order by score ) t`, but it comes out:

```
group_id
A
B
C
```

the same to `select group_id from (select  group_id from table  order by score ) t group by group_id`.

however, the expected result is

```
group_id
B
C
A
```

I think this should be easy, just need someone show the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
select group_id
from table 
group by group_id
order by min(score);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This make things nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `SUM` funcion to order groups by score, e.g.

```
SELECT group_id
FROM table
GROUP BY group_id
ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC;
```

If you want to order by individual entry or aggregate value then you can replace `SUM` with any other aggregation function (like `MAX`, `AVG` etc). [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) is the documentation for MySQL's group/aggregation functions.

Comment: Thanks, I know `group by` usually works with aggregation function, but in this situation. I just want to do the comparison with `score` in a single row, and grab the associate `group_id`

Comment: In that case, as I explained below my answer, replacing `ORDER BY SUM(score)` with `ORDER BY MIN(score)` should do the job for you.

Comment: Yes, you'r right.  i figure that out now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> so, i think this will work `select distinct group_id from (select  group_id from table  order by score ) t`

The inner query can be assimilated to a table. Your query is `select distinct group_id from t` and MySQL has no reason to order the returned rows by score or by any other column.

> the same to `select group_id from (select  group_id from table  order by score ) t group by group_id`.

Again, there is no request for MySQL to order the rows. `GROUP BY` doesn't order and it produces a different thing, anyway. You don't need it.

The query you need is expressed in your question:

> I want to get distinct group_id order by score.

Put in SQL it is as simple as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT group_by
FROM table
ORDER BY score
```

Comment: so, any solution?